# How can I make these axes to the end of the last tick?

Tags: plotting, functions

I'm posting this again as it hasn't solved and some weird guys just like to vote close without ever reading the post or giving a solution.

The suggestion by – Bob Hanlon does not exactly same as my question. I wanted to make the length of axes exactly same as the last tick. 
Also the suggestion doesn't work in  13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit).

How can I make these axes longer (to the end of the last tick)?

The comment kind of works but what if I want to make them longer exactly same as the end of the last tick? Is there any way to do it other than manually trial and error?  
Another problem with the suggestion is that `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]` remove the label `0`.

[image]

```
Show[Plot[x, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 5}}], 
 Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 5}}], 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.005], 12], 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

From suggestion with `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.01]` you can see that the label 0 is not there.
(13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit))

```
Show[Plot[x, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 5}}], 
 Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 5}}], 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.005], 12], 
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.01]]
```

[image]

Comment: With either v13.0.1 or v13.1 on a Mac, `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.01]` displays the `0`  Edit your question to show what you get using `PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[.01], {None, Scaled[.01]}}`

Answer (score 4):

Specifying the Padding individually for each edge brings back the 0 at the origin and allows for the vertical padding to be corrected by the aspect ratio. Documentation states thickness of tick is relative to the horizontal plot range.
This scales well with different image sizes and plot ranges.

```
ar = GoldenRatio;
Show[Plot[x, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 5}}], 
 Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 5}}], 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.005], 12], 
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[.0025], Scaled[.0025]}, {0, 
    Scaled[.0025*ar]}}, TicksStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.005]], 
 AspectRatio -> 1/ar]
```

[image]